# Volume of a solid bounded by cylinders and planes

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid in $\mathbb{R^{3}}$ bounded by the cylinders $y^{2}+z^{2}=1$, $y^{2}+z^{2}=4$ and the planes $x=-1$, $x+z=3$. I'm not sure how to find the region of integration for this question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the cylindrical coordinates to set up the volume integral as

$$V = \int_{(y,z)}[(3-z)-(-1)]dydz $$
$$= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^2(4-r\sin\theta)rdrd\theta
= \int_0^{2\pi}\left(6-\frac73\sin\theta\right)d\theta=12\pi$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Often the problem is easier once you can visualize the domain.  You can think of the volume as the intersection of

1. the volume between two cylinders centered on the x-axis, and
2. the region between two planes  (a wedge).

When a cylinder is cut by two planes, the resulting volume is often $\pi r^2 h$ where $r$ is the radius of the cylinders and $h$ is the distance between the points where the planes cut the central axis.  This problem can be solved without calculus, though it is a good exercise to do the calculus as given by Quanto.

If you are having trouble visualize the volume, look at the image below.
[image]